# java-Match a regex pattern in a string(listing matching and non-matching parts)

Tags: java, regex, string, match

i have a csv string containing five fields(3 mandatory and 2 optional). The optional fields are in posiition 3 and 5.
I have a regex pattern to identify the strings in double quotes

```
    private static final String TEXT_IN_DBL_QUOTES_REGEX="\"([^\"]*)\"";
    private static final String rowData="\"Field1\", \"Field2\", , \"Field4\", ";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> fields = Lists.newArrayList();
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(TEXT_IN_DBL_QUOTES_REGEX);
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(rowData);
        while(matcher.find()){
           fields.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
        return fields;
    }

My expected result is an array list containing 
Field1, Field2, null, Field4, null
but the above is returning 
Field1, Field2, Field4
```

How can i tweak the above code to get the desired result?

Comment: Using above regex still gave me the below
    "Domain Name","13test.com", ,"USer5", 
    ==>[Domain Name, 13test.com, USer5]

Comment: why not use a CSV Reader that has full support for quoted fields? http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Architecturally I cannot use this api call until the api is approved for use in our environment and moreover there is ambiguity on the delimiter as "," because I have comma separated text as a value for the field.

Thanks for responding though...

Comment: The CSV-Lib can handle Strings containing "," as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tweak your regex like this:

```
String TEXT_IN_DBL_QUOTES_REGEX="\"([^\"]*)\"|(?<=,) *(?=,|$)";
String rowData="\"Field1\", \"Field2\", , \"Field4\", ";

List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(TEXT_IN_DBL_QUOTES_REGEX);
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(rowData);
while(matcher.find()) {
    fields.add(matcher.group(1));
}
System.out.println (fields);
```

**Output:**

```
[Field1, Field2, null, Field4, null]
```

Comment: But this fails if a string inside the csv is supposed to contain an `"`, for example `"Field1", "This is ""quoted""", , "Field4"` - according to csv-standards a double quote inside a double quoted field has to be preceded with a double quote.

Comment: Right for those cases it is better to use a csv parser library.

Comment: for now my requirements prevent a string to contain a double-quote
so I am good with the solution for now